# Android Studio: Unable to locate ADB

Tags: android, adb

I was working in Android Studio and after I closed my laptop to eat and opened it again Android Studio claims it cannot find ADB anymore.

Unable to find ADB

[image: Unable to find ADB]

- I have restarted my PC, Android Studio and my phone multiple times.
- I have reinstalled ADB multiple times.
- I have reinstalled the Android SDK.
- I have addded adb.exe to my path variables

All had no effect and I'm still stuck on this error.

Does somebody have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run following commands

```
adb kill-server
```

then

```
adb start-server
```

It resolves your issue with ADB

Comment: I swear I had done this already, but anyway it worked! Thanks! Any idea how the server got killed in the first place?